# Laravel Eloquent - belongs to many through

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have sites, pages, elements and element_creators tables, like this :

```
   sites
     id
     ...
   pages
     id
     site_id
     ...
   elements
     id
     page_id
     ...
   element_creators
     id
     element_id
     ...
```

I'm able to retrieve element creators linked to a page

```
    $this->belongsToMany('ElementCreator', 'elements', 'page_id', 'element_creator_id');
```

Is there a simple way to retrieve all element creators for a specific site (through its pages) ?

Thank you !

Comment: There's something wrong with this code: it's either not `belongsToMany` relation pages->creators (rather hasManyThrough) or those tables have different schema to what you wrote. There are possible solutions depending on that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$site = Site::with('pages.elementCreators')->find(1); // 1 is id for example
```

Then you may access all the `elementCreators` using this:

```
$elementCreators = $site->pages->fetch('elementCreators');
```

Comment: It works. But, is there another simpler way to do that for now?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm using this as a temporary solution, I hope to find something better :

```
    public function elementCreators()
    {
        $elementCreators = array();
            foreach ($this->pages as $page) {
                foreach ($page->elementCreators as $elementCreator) {
                    $elementCreators[$elementCreator->id] = $elementCreator;
                }
            }
        return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::make($elementCreators);
    }
```